# Questions of difference of integer squares being semiprime

Tags: number-theory, factoring, semiprimes

I searched a lot, but found no answers to my questions.

I am interested in difference of integer squares being semiprime (RSA number) and posted about:
[Odd prime iff unique difference of 2 squares](https://github.com/Hermann-SW/Mathematical-expressions/blob/main/Number%20theory/Odd%20prime%20iff%20unique%20difference%20of%202%20squares.md)

Is it known that

1. an odd prime *p* has a unique difference of squares $p = (\frac{p+1}{2})^2 - (\frac{p-1}{2})^2$?
2. semi prime $n=p*q$ with odd primes $p, q$ has exactly two differences of squares, the "canonical" of (1) and $n = (2a+1)(2b+1) = (a+b+1)^2 + (b-a)^2$?
3. if non-canonical difference of squares is known for semi prime $n = c^2 - d^2$ with $c-d > 1$, then factorization of $n$ is easy, its two prime factors are just $c+d$ and $c-d$?

Any links or references are welcome.

[.square_diffs()](https://github.com/Hermann-SW/RSA_numbers_factored/blob/main/python/RSA_numbers_factored.py#L710-L715):

```
>>> from RSA_numbers_factored import RSA, digits
>>> RSA = RSA()
>>> l,n,p,q = RSA.get(59)[0:4]
>>> l == digits(n) == 59
True
>>> n == p*q
True
>>> RSA.square_diffs(59)
[[278934861111101959940264512227, 78505642990286405670520876790], [35820760380875717727566808237833545217031666114123935897715, 35820760380875717727566808237833545217031666114123935897714]]
>>> for a,b in RSA.square_diffs(59):
...     n == a**2 - b**2
... 
True
True
>>>
```

Comment: Of course this is known, as it is a trivial consequence of $c^2-d^2=(c+d)(c-d)$. Differences of squares exactly correspond to factorization into two factors (of the same parity).

Comment: Any link for questions 1-3?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

Comment: This is also why in RSA you never want the two primes to be too close to each other (and for similar reasons you don't want the largest to be a near multiple of the smallest).

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. The quotient of prime factors of RSA numbers factored sofar (biggest RSA-250) are between 1.0 and 2.2. Only exception is oldest RSA challenge from 1977 (RSA-129) with factor 9.4:   
[https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=343468#p2078266](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=343468#p2078266)